# How are high accuracy grinding stones and disks made?

Tags: manufacturing-engineering, machining, grinding

Generally speaking cutters such as end-mills and often lead screws are ground vs shaped using a sharp cutter.

I am curious how are high accuracy grinding wheels made? Their very nature seems to be fundamentally not precise yet they are used to create very precise tools.

Comment: https://www.nortonabrasives.com/en-us/resources/expertise/history-and-innovation-behind-zirconia-alumina http://www.difference.minaprem.com/machining/difference-between-machining-and-grinding/#:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there such thing as a "high-accuracy" grinding wheel? What does "high-accuracy" even mean in this context? If you mean of a precise dimension, then no. Grinding wheels wear and with the small amounts of material they are intended to remove, they are used to aim for tighter tolerances so small amounts of wear matters proportionally more than with other tools. Therefore you dress the to size with a diamond. The more precise you need the dimension the more often you dress them. There are finer grinding wheels but that doesn't mean high accuracy; It just means they leave a finer finish.

Comment: The granules on the stones are usually pretty big though? I don't understand how they can be used to grind high-precision items like lead screws or end-mills because of this.

Comment: @FourierFlux You just need enough of them randomly distributed so that every point along the path is hit. Not unlike how you can't see through a brush with layers and layers of bristles even though the bristles are discrete.